# Posting JSON to server using single string

Tags: android, json, post

I am posting data to server as single string. Its not posting. I am getting response.

I tried volley and retrofit. but I want to try in normal HTTP connection. I don't want to use other thing

```
    String api_url = "http://mywebsite.com/blah_blah";
  String book_now_request = "user_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_id, "UTF-8") + "&src=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(src), "UTF-8") + "&src_lng=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(src_lng) , "UTF-8" );



  JSONObject response_data = call_api(api_url, book_now_request);

  public JSONObject call_api(String api_url, String request_data) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(api_url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            Log.e("request_data", request_data);

            writer.write(request_data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            String response = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }

            Log.d("API response", response);

            JSONObject response_data = new JSONObject(response);
            Log.e("J Response",response_data.toString());
            return response_data;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue that you are facing

Comment: I'm getting wrong response that mean It's not post properly

Comment: Is this format correct?

Comment: If you are fetching data from body using POST method, then try to fetch data using raw  data from server end. What response you are getting

Comment: I have to post this data to server. If this data is correct.. server will return success. or else it will return data not posted. I am getting data not posted. my doubt is this string will converted into json object and post or it will post as raw data

Comment: try to read raw response data from server which help you find whether data is reached at server or not. If you found data, then their may be issue in handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand your problem. Your passing it as raw data. You need to format it to JSON data.

```
String book_now_request = "{\"user_id\":\"key\",\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

Just try this. Hope this will work. Have a nice day!

Comment: I was posting it like url. now it works. thanks again